# configure: error: Please install libyaml

Tags: fedora, php, fedora-20, yaml

I am following the installation of [Basics of YAML Parsing in PHP](http://www.v-nessa.net/2012/06/22/basics-of-yaml-parsing-in-php) to install YAML for PHP in Fedora 20.

I went through all these steps:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/yaml-1.1.0.tgz
tar -xvzf yaml-1.1.0.tgz
cd yaml-1.1.0
phpize
./configure && make && make install
```

But the last one does not work:

```
# ./configure && make && make install
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
.../...
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable LibYAML suppot... yes, shared
checking for yaml headers... not found
configure: error: Please install libyaml
```

As I get the "Please install libyaml", I checked whether it is installed... and it is!

```
# yum list installed | grep yaml
libyaml.x86_64                         0.1.6-1.fc20                    @updates 
yaml-cpp03.x86_64                      0.3.0-4.fc20                    @anaconda
```

And of course if I create a php file with a call to `yaml_parse_file()`, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file() in XXXfile on line YYY
```

What can be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this wasn't intended to end like this, but I found a solution through [Howto Install with Pecl](https://code.google.com/p/php-yaml/wiki/InstallingWithPecl) documentation in Code Google:

- Install LibYAML using your favorite method. For example on a Ubuntu machine `sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev` will get what you need.
- `sudo pecl install yaml-beta`
- Edit your php.ini settings and add `extension=yaml.so`
- See if it worked with `php --re yaml`

As I am on Fedora, I had to use a slightly different approach:

```
# yum search yaml | grep -i php
php-symfony-YAML.noarch : The Symfony YAML Component
php-pecl-yaml.x86_64 : PHP Bindings for yaml
php-symfony-yaml.noarch : Symfony Yaml Component
php-symfony2-Yaml.noarch : Symfony2 Yaml Component
php54-php-pecl-yaml.x86_64 : PHP Bindings for yaml
php56-php-pecl-yaml.x86_64 : PHP Bindings for yaml
syck.i686 : YAML for C, Python, and PHP
syck.x86_64 : YAML for C, Python, and PHP
syck-php.x86_64 : YAML module for php
```

So I installed `php-pecl-yaml.x86_64`:

```
# yum install php-pecl-yaml.x86_64
```

I added the line into my `php.ini` file, restarted apache just in case and now I get a good output from:

```
# php --re yaml
Extension [ <persistent> extension #16 yaml version 1.1.1 ] {

  - Dependencies {
    Dependency [ date (Optional) ]
  }

  - INI {
    Entry [ yaml.decode_binary <ALL> ]
      Current = '0'
    }
    Entry [ yaml.decode_timestamp <ALL> ]
      Current = '0'
    }
    Entry [ yaml.output_canonical <ALL> ]
      Current = '0'

    .../...

    Function [ <internal:yaml> function yaml_emit_file ] {

      - Parameters [5] {
        Parameter #0 [ <required> $filename ]
        Parameter #1 [ <required> $data ]
        Parameter #2 [ <optional> $encoding ]
        Parameter #3 [ <optional> $linebreak ]
        Parameter #4 [ <optional> array $callbacks ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install libyaml-dev, not libyaml. On CentOS, I installed it with `sudo yum install -y libyaml-devel.x86_64`.

```
[vagrant@localhost yaml-1.2.0]$ yum search libyaml
============================================
N/S Matched: libyaml
============================================
libyaml-devel.i686 : Development files for LibYAML applications
libyaml-devel.x86_64 : Development files for LibYAML applications
libyaml.i686 : YAML 1.1 parser and emitter written in C
libyaml.x86_64 : YAML 1.1 parser and emitter written in C
```

Comment: It's in powertools (for Centos 8 and related distros anyway). `sudo dnf --enablerepo=powertools install libyaml-devel`